# Nginx - access from a public ip address - ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, ubuntu, dns, ip, nginx

An nginx server is up and running locally on my system[ubuntu 14.04]. But i am having difficulty accessing the same server from my public ip address, or from any other system using my public ip address. I have just started looking into nginx, its been great, but am stuck at this point now.

> Issue : Nothing displays when i use my public ip address in the
>   browser.

below is the config file "firstsite.com"

```
server {
        listen   80 default_server;
        server_name firstsite.com;

        root /var/www/uwsgiSite;
        index index.html;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ index.html;
                allow all;
        }
}
```

which is available in "sites-available" and soft linked into "sites-enabled" folders. Also i have an entry in the /etc/hosts file

```
127.0.0.1   firstsite.com
```

All the folders/files are available in /var/www with permission.

Later i would like to connect the same with a domain name [buy purchasing one] to my computer. For now, i am looking to make it work just with my public ip address, which is not working yet. Please guide me as to what is missing to make it accessible.

Answer (score 0):

127.0.0.1 is a local-only loopback address, and is local ONLY to this system you have it setup on, it is not even accessible to the network to a laptop on the same network right next to it.  Please search Google for "127.0.0.0/8 loopback special use" to understand why.